# crl vs ocsp revocation with iText

Tags: itext, digital-signature, ocsp

I have read all the white papers on the subject, successfully signed certified and time stamped my pdf document, but confusion arises when I want to do revocation.
  When I don't implement crl or ocsp in my signature properties/revocation I get that ocsp revocation check was done online.
  If I implement crl, I get this :

[image]

If I implement ocsp, or ocsp and crl together, I get this:

[image]

My question would be: ocsp in my case obviously has a priority, that should be down to my CA, in this case Start Com class 1, am i right? and is this a good way to implement both(because as it looks i can only see ocsp even dough I implemented both). and why is it, in both cases, check revocation button grayed out? what am I missing?

Comment: *i can only see ocsp even dough I implemented both* - A verifier usually accepts non-revocation as soon as one source says so. Which source is tested first is up to the verifier. And obviously the displayed information concerning revocation should reflect why the verifier assumes non-revocation.

Comment: so if I got it correctly, everything is in order? thanks mkl

Comment: *everything is in order* - as far as I can tell from the information given, there is no apparent problem.

Comment: thanks, I thought so myself...but wanted someone with more knowledge to confirm that it is up to verifier to choose between ocsp and crl..in this case ocsp. thanks again mkl, more than helpfull as usual